# spring batch job parameters to recurring operation

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, parameters, quartz-scheduler, spring-batch

I have a basic spring batch job (spring-core-3.1.1) application setup running with quartz scheduler (1.8.6). it looks like this,

```
     - spring batch job has a mysql datasource to save job states in spring batch schema 
     - job Reader is a csvFile reader using class org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader
     - Writer is simple custom ItemWriter (output is on console)
     - quartz scheduler is used to setup crontrigger alongwith jobdetail bean
     - scheudler runs the job every 10 seconds (*/10 * * * * ?)
```

I want to customize this setup by reading the CSV file for only X number of lines per job instance instead of reading the whole file e.g. if there are 10 lines in a file, and I want to read 2 lines per step, then the job instance should read only 2 lines instead of 10 atonce. For that I want to give the job dynamic params based on the number of lines read. So that for each job execution the job instance have unique and incrementing params. Like a cursor to the file reader.

How to achieve it?

My jobdetail property for param

```
  <property name="jobDataAsMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="jobName" value="reportJob" />
            <entry key="jobLocator" value-ref="jobRegistry" />
            <entry key="jobLauncher" value-ref="jobLauncher" />
            <entry key="cursor" value="0"/> 
                <!-- Gives error on this one: <entry key="cursor" value="#{jobParameters['cursor']}"/>
        </map>
    </property>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read latest successfully completed job parameters to detect latest starting line then add 2 to this value and call the new job.
You can read job tables metadata using [JobExplorer](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/index.html?org/springframework/batch/core/explore/JobExplorer.html) or directly query spring-batch's [meta-data tables](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/metaDataSchema.html)

Comment: You mean, I have to manually read 2 lines per job execution and everytime update the JobParamers like builder.addDouble("cursor", x+2); ?

Comment: yes. every new job starts with updated "cursor" param based on last job

Comment: how to send jobparameter to quartz launcher so that it gets the incremented parameter value always. I increment it in quartz getJobParametersFromJobMap() but it always reads 0